# Trying to figure out why my project is not running right

Tags: c#, arrays, file

My program reads from a text file delimited with a comma. The answers are an array of strings which I can't get to populate at the console.

The Question will show up, the correct Answer(a single char) will show up and the explanation will show up, it is just the array with the answers I am having problems with.

I will supply the code below.

The Question Unit( Structure of the Questions from the text file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HoodTalkTrivia
{
    class QuestionUnit
    {
        private string correctAnswer;
        private string explanation;
        private string question;
        private string[] answer = new string[4];

        public string CorrectAnswer
        {
            get { return correctAnswer; }
            set { correctAnswer = value; }
        }
        public string Explanation
        {
            get { return explanation; }
            set { explanation = value; }
        }
        public string Question
        {
            get { return question; }
            set { question = value; }
        }
        public string[] Answer
        {
            get {return answer; }
            set { answer = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

The Question Bank

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace HoodTalkTrivia
{
    class QuestionBank
    {
        List<QuestionUnit> theQuestionsList = new List<QuestionUnit>();

       // private string[] Questions;
       const int NUM_ANSWERS = 4;
       const int NUM_QUESTIONS = 5;

       public int GetNumberOfAnswers
       {
           get { return NUM_ANSWERS; }
       }
       public int GetNumberOfQuestions
       {
           get { return NUM_QUESTIONS; }
       }
       public string GetCorrectAnswer(int index)
       {
           return theQuestionsList[index].CorrectAnswer;
       }
       public string GetExplanation(int index)
       {
           return theQuestionsList[index].Explanation;
       }
       public string GetQuestion(int index)
       {
           return theQuestionsList[index].Question;
       }
       public string[] GetAnswer(int index)
       {
           return theQuestionsList[index].Answer;
       }
       public bool ReadQuestionFile()
       {
           bool success = true;

           FileInfo httSourceFile = new FileInfo("Questions.txt");
           string line;
           string[] fields;
           char[] delimiter = { System.Convert.ToChar(",") };
           QuestionUnit httQuestionUnit;
           //int i = 0;

           try
           {
               StreamReader httReader = httSourceFile.OpenText();

               line = httReader.ReadLine();

               while (line != null)
               {
                   httQuestionUnit = new QuestionUnit();

                   fields = line.Split(delimiter);

                   httQuestionUnit.Question = fields[0];

                   string[] aArray =  new string[4];

                   aArray[0] = fields[1];                    
                   aArray[1] = fields[2];
                   aArray[2] = fields[3];
                   aArray[3] = fields[4];

                   httQuestionUnit.Answer = aArray;
                   httQuestionUnit.CorrectAnswer = fields[5];
                   httQuestionUnit.Explanation = fields[6];


                   theQuestionsList.Add(httQuestionUnit);

                   line = httReader.ReadLine();
               }

           }
           catch
           {
               success = false;
           }
           return success;
       }

   }
}
```

And the main

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HoodTalkTrivia
{
    class HoodTalkTriviaGame
    {
        HoodTalkTriviaStrings myGameStrings;


        public void PlayAgain()
        {
        }

        public void Play()
        {
            QuestionBank myQuestions = new QuestionBank();
            DisplayWelcome();

            myQuestions.ReadQuestionFile();

            for (int i = 0; i < myQuestions.GetNumberOfQuestions; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myQuestions.GetQuestion(i));

                for (int j = 0; j < myQuestions.GetNumberOfAnswers; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(myQuestions.GetAnswer(j));
                }
                // Console.WriteLine(myQuestions.GetCorrectAnswer(i));
                Console.WriteLine("Make a selection, A - D");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }




        }

        public void DisplayWelcome()
        {
            myGameStrings = new HoodTalkTriviaStrings();

            myGameStrings.WelcomeString();
        }

        public char PromptForGuess()
        {
            char guess = ' ';


            return guess;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an image of what i am getting at the console.[image: apprunning]

Answer (score 1):

`GetAnswer` method returning an array of strings, so you are seeing the name of the type of your array in the console instead of the contents.

You can change your code like this:

Change this code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < myQuestions.GetNumberOfAnswers; j++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(myQuestions.GetAnswer(j));
}
```

To:

```
var answers = myQuestions.GetAnswer(i);
for (int j = 0; j < answers.Length; j++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(answers[j]);
}
```

Then you should see the answers of your question in the console.

Comment: Thanks, That worked like a charm I need to know how you immediately caught that, I have been staring at this for over 18 hours. You ROCK!!! StackOverflow Rocks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the second index for the possible answers, because `Answer` is an array again:

```
for (int j = 0; j < myQuestions.GetNumberOfAnswers; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myQuestions.GetAnswer(i)[j]);
}
```

An alternative way of solving the problem is to change the acessor method:

```
public string GetAnswer(int questionIndex, int answerIndex)
{
    return theQuestionsList[questionIndex].Answer[answerIndex];
}
```

And then the loop will be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < myQuestions.GetNumberOfAnswers; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myQuestions.GetAnswer(i, j));
}
```

Now the signature of the `GetAnswer` makes it impossible to forget the second index. It would also be helpful to rename the `Answer` property to `Answers`. This would remind you that an array is returned.

---

I think your solution a bit over-designed. An overall simplified approach would make it easier to use the classes. If the `QuestionBank` simply had a property returning an enumeration of question units this would be enough. No need for all the `GetXYZ` methods.

```
class QuestionBank
{
    List<QuestionUnit> theQuestionsList = new List<QuestionUnit>();

    public IEnumerable<QuestionUnit> Questions { get { return theQuestionsList; } }

    ...
}
```

Returning an `IEnumerable<QuestionUnit>` has the advantage over returning a `List<QuestionUnit>` that the real type of the question list is not made public, thus allowing you to change the implementation at any time without invalidating any code that accesses the questions from the outside.

Then the loops will become easier:

```
foreach (QuestionUnit questionUnit in myQuestions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(questionUnit.Question);

    foreach (string answer in questionUnit.Answers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Make a selection, A - D");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```